# MongooseIM SSL connection via AWS ELB

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, xmpp, ejabberd

I have MongooseIM server configured with docker-compose in an EC2 instance in AWS.

I intend to give access to some mobile clients with SSL through an ELB (AWS) on port 5222 (module ejabberd_c2s of mongooseim) in the following way:

(ignore de 5285 SSL config, it's for BOSH module and works fine)

[ELB AWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQGh2.png)

In the ejabberd_c2s module configuration I have the following:

```
  { 5222, ejabberd_c2s, [

                    %%
                    %% If TLS is compiled in and you installed a SSL
                    %% certificate, specify the full path to the
                    %% file and uncomment this line:
                    %%
                    {certfile, "priv/ssl/fake_server.pem"}, starttls,

                    %%{zlib, 10000},
                    %% https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html#CIPHER_STRINGS
                    %% {ciphers, "DEFAULT:!EXPORT:!LOW:!SSLv2"},
                    {access, c2s},
                    {shaper, c2s_shaper},
                    {max_stanza_size, 65536},
                    {protocol_options, ["no_sslv3"]}

                   ]},
```

But customers can not connect, the only message I get on the server is this:

```
mongooseim_server_dev | 10:58:25.885 [info] (#Port<0.27608>) Accepted connection {{10,0,17,246},42571} -> {{172,18,0,2},5222}
mongooseim_server_dev | 10:58:25.885 [debug] Received XML on stream = "���yw�\��.ndEt�;�����fn�A>� n:�=5��</A
 "ngooseim_server_dev | ��kj98����g@32ED�(#
mongooseim_server_dev | 10:58:25.885 [debug] Send XML on stream = <<"<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' id='2B421BCD2D077161' from='localhost' version='1.0'>">>
mongooseim_server_dev | 10:58:25.886 [debug] Send XML on stream = <<"<stream:error><xml-not-well-formed xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'/></stream:error>">>
mongooseim_server_dev | 10:58:25.886 [debug] Send XML on stream = <<"</stream:stream>">>
```

The Mongoose documentation does not offer me any solution and I do not see anyone with this error.

Any help or clue?